# Why does ReturnUrl return null parameter though it shows up in the adress bar?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What could be the reason for **returnUrl** string getting back asthe null value though it's printed in the adress bar. In he form I've created hidden input tag in order to catch URL and pass it into the ActionResult parameter :

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, ))
        {
                 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                 <input type="hidden" value="@Url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]"/>
               <input type="submit" value="Enter" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        }
```

So after hitting submit button I'm redirected to the Account controller/ Login ActionResult with the ReturnUrl parameter being null

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model,string ReturnUrl)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               //some codes
                    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ReturnUrl))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("HomeIndex", "Home");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("UserLoginError", "Username or password is incorrect");
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

I've also tried to add the querystring as a parameter inside the brackets of Beginform like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] } ))
```

Didn't work either.

Comment: What kind of URL returned in `Url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]` and `Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]`? If both of them are null or empty string, try `HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.Query`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're using hidden field to store return URL for redirection, which will sent as part of `Request.Form` collection instead of individual action parameter inside controller's POST action method. To make sure that return URL is included during form submit, I suggest you to add return URL property in the viewmodel first:

```
public class LoginModel
{
    // other existing properties

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Then set the value inside GET action which renders login form:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    var model = new LoginModel() { ReturnUrl = returnUrl };
    return View(model);
}
```

And you could provide a hidden field inside the form to hold its value:

```
@* using input hidden tag *@
<input name="ReturnUrl" value="@Model.ReturnUrl" type="hidden" />

@* using HTML helper *@
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReturnUrl)
```

Finally, the return URL may be passed inside `LoginModel` instance, no need to provide additional parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //some codes
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.ReturnUrl))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("HomeIndex", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("UserLoginError", "Username or password is incorrect");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: quite simple and sensible way out  ..deserved to be accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing `name` tag for `input`

```
<input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="@Url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]"/>
```

The name attribute must be the same as action paremeter name.

Comment: Nice detection Alex. The problem was sorted out